# How to setup a VPN connection using qt?

Tags: qt

I want to build a Qt application which creates a VPN connection using [PPTP server](http://www.bestukvpn.com)

I have searched for that and found the code to use proxy connection in Qt as following. But the code does not work. When I run the application, and then check my IP address, the IP address does not change, it is the same as the previous (i.e. No VPN connection is established).

I am actually a beginner for Qt. So, do I have to code something more using some other Qt classes or there is an error in my approach ?

```
void MainWindow::enableVPN(){
     proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);
     proxy.setHostName("www.bestukvpn.com");
     proxy.setPort(999);
     proxy.setUser("free");
     QString pass=ui->PassField->text();
     qDebug() << pass;
     proxy.setPassword(pass);
     QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);
}
```

Comment: I found this https://github.com/JevonQ/VPN-client

Answer (score 2):

You are aware that HTTP proxies are *not* VPNs? Normally VPNs are established at OS level and using virtual network interfaces.

One way to have some control over it would possibly be to use (for instance) an OpenVPN command line binary and control that through the `QProcess` API - but that's not PPTP.

Comment: No, I thought both the things work similalry..;)..so can't we establish PPTP VPN connection through Qt ?

Comment: Not directly. Also you didn't mention which OS this is supposed to run on. Windows? Mac OS? Linux? Mobile devices? PPTP requires some low-level stuff like GRE packets and virtual network interfaces that are almost impossible to do with a high-level framework like Qt.

Comment: Ideally , it should run on all the platforms ;)...So , anyother way of establishing VPN connection ?

Comment: Well, start with reading about what a VPN is before you start this stuff. Wikipedia and google are quite helpful.